# Is it "Whom" or "Who"/"Which"?

Tags: word-choice, reflexive-pronouns

English is not my native language so I don't know it very well.

I'm trying to learn when to use whom, which, and who.

> I can't find my new coat _____ I bought last week.

Could someone explain to me which one is correct and why?

Comment: The coat is not a living thing, it's just an object, so we use 'which'. Use 'who/whom' with people and, if you like, animals, especially pets

Comment: You could also use "that", **or** since the relative word is object of the relative clause, you could omit it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find my new *coat* [(which/that) I bought last week].

This sentence has got a relative clause which refers to the object **coat** and can be introduced with conjunctions *which* or *that* because the noun isn't a living thing. Since it refers to an object it can be left out in an essential clause. *Who* is used referring to people or (sometimes) pets.